# how to create two button with individual events through IB in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

in my application i will create 3 subclass. when i press one subclass button it wil goes navigate to next page and another page is navigate to another page. in last subclass when i press the button wants to go next page, it contain errors and it not goes to another page. i develop designs thru IB. but it shows Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” in console page. what i do here.? anyone pls help..

my code

```
@interface Navigate : UIViewController {
UILabel *label;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
- (IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender; 
@end

implementation page:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 }
 - (IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
 label.text=@"Hello World";
 }
```

i cant procede this page. pls help me.

Comment: `self.label.text = @"Hello World";` and also set outlet to label.

Comment: i correctly set outlet also but i cant get answer. what i do....

Comment: Do you have any warning or something else in Navigate.m file

Answer (score 0):

May be you have released something.or you are accessing the Null Pointer

Answer (score 0):

first you create a object of class to which you want to display and use this
classVC *_obj=[[classVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"classNibname" bundle:nil];
[self presentmodelviewcontroller:_obj animated:YES];

Use this to go to another view